# C# WPF Shared Project Failed to Recognize GUI Controls and Routines in Code

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wcf, project

I created a solution with 2 shared projects. One (named LightZ) is used for WCF platforms, the other (named LightZ-Desktop) is used for desktop application. These two projects share a log of dialogs. The dialog code always starts with something like

<Window x:Class="LightZ.dlgForecast"

Since I want to share these dialogs, I used "LightZ" as the assembly name in both projects.

Initially, everything seems to be working fine. Both projects compiles (with a conditional compilation variable DESKTOP to separate these two). However, when I add a new dialog to LightZ, then share it on LightZ-Desktop, the project LightZ-Desktop blow up!! Everything with GUI controls and components fail to compile. I get all kinds of errors like this:

[image]

I've examined the project folders and it seems to me that only the LightZ-Desktop.csproj file was modified. However, even if I copy this file from a backup copy to overwrite the current one, the error persisted!! I had to copy the entire backup project back to remove the error. Something else was going on.

Can anyone provide any explanation to this and how to fix (or get around it)?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem by doing the following:

1. Instead of using a different folder "LightZ-Desktop", I created a second project LightZ-Desktop.csproj and placed it in the same folder "LightZ" as the original project LightZ.csproj.
2. In the same home folder for the solution that includes LightZ.csproj, I created a second solution that includes LightZ-Desktop.csproj (and other needed components).
3. Both projects and solutions access the same set of files from the same folder "LightZ" (as opposed to previous setup where "LightZ" holds the files while "LightZ-Desktop" shares the files from the folder "LightZ-Desktop").
4. This set up allows both solutions and projects to use the same assembly name "LightZ" (the previous setup, the 2nd project was default to use assembly name "LightZ-Desktop", and that created all kinds of conflicts).